# Numpy flipped coordinate system

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I used opencv to do some image processing. I tried to then plot the image on my plotter (origin at lower left), however the image is flipped. opencv's origin is in the upper left, and so the y coordinates of the image are flipped.[image: origin in upper left]

What function should I apply to my points such that it will plot properly in the new origin system (lower left)?

EDIT:
I am not concerned with changing the plot display, I actually need the points' coordinates flipped.
Using np.flipud did not change the points at all since the point are displayed by a N X 2 matrix.

Answer (score 5):

The problem does not lie in numpy but in matplotlib way of displaying data. In order to produce valid visualization you should flip y-axis on the *image generation* level, not numpy analysis. It can be easily done through matplitlib API to the axes object:

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: You can also specify `origin='lower'` or `origin='upper'` to `imshow` if you're using matplotlib.  However, I'm not sure if the OP is or not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to flip a numpy array or how to display it?

If you're asking how to flip the array, have a look at `np.flipud` or equivalently `your_data[::-1, ...]`

---

`numpy.flipud` is a function that uses the exact slicing shown above.  However, it's more readable if you're not familiar with numpy slicing.

To explain why `data[::-1, ...]` will flip the array vertically, you need to understand a bit about how indexing works.

In general, indexing in python works by specifying `start:stop:step`.  Each of these may be None (e.g. `:-10` specifies `start=None`, `stop=-10`, `step=None`).

Therefore, `::-1` specifies `start=None`, `stop=None`, `step=-1` -- in other words, go over the full sequence, but increment with a negative step, effectively reversing the sequence.

`...` is an `Ellipsis`.  In numpy, this is used to indicate including all other dimensions.

The ellipsis avoids the need to special case your array being 2D or 3D (or 27-dimensional, for that matter).  If it's a 2D array, then `x[::-1, ...]` is equivalent to `x[::-1, :]`.  If it's a 3D array, it's equivalent to `x[::-1, :, :]`, etc.

In numpy, the first axis is rows.  Therefore, `x[::-1, ...]` says "reverse the rows and leave all other dimensions alone.  This will create a view, so the memory wont' be duplicated and no copy will be created.

In the specific case of rows, you could leave the ellipsis out.  However, it's useful to think about for the general case.  For example, flipping left-right would be `x[:, ::-1, ...]` (or `np.fliplr`).