# Change origin of image coordinate system to bottom left instead of default top left

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, matplotlib

Is there a simple way of changing the origin of image co-ordinate system of OpenCV to bottom left? Using `numpy` for example? I am using OpenCv 2.4.12 and Python 2.7.

Related: [Numpy flipped coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527016/numpy-flipped-coordinate-system), but this talks about just display. I want something which I can use consistently in my algorithm.

Update:

```
def imread(*args, **kwargs):
    img = plt.imread(*args, **kwargs)
    img = np.flipud(img)
    return img      
#read reference image using cv2.imread
imref=cv2.imread('D:\\users\\gayathri\\all\\new\\CoilA\\Resized_Results\\coilA_1.png',-1)
cv2.circle(imref, (0,0),30,(0,0,255),2,8,0)
cv2.imshow('imref',imref)

#read the same image using imread function
im=imread('D:\\users\\gayathri\\all\\new\\CoilA\\Resized_Results\\coilA_1.png',-1)
img= im.copy()
cv2.circle(img, (0,0),30,(0,0,255),2,8,0)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Image read using cv2.imread:
[image: original image]

Image flipped using imread function:
[image: flipped]

As seen the circle is drawn at the origin on upper left corner in both original and flipped image. But the image looks flipped which I do not desire.

Comment: Just change the `y` values after the OpenCV calls, unless you mean to change the OpenCV source codes themselves, which might too much of work.

Comment: @ZdaR I thought OpenCV follows top left corner as origin.

Comment: How about `numpy.flip(img, axis=0)` or `numpy.flpud(img)` (assuming `img` is the image array)?

Comment: What if OP could efficiently flip the matrix along the x-axis ? it would be a one time operation and would serve the purpose given that operation is not costly ?

Comment: @Divakar You are right it follows top-left corner as origin, my bad

Comment: @ZdaR that is exactly what I wish for! Its a long image processing chain and I just want to do it once.

Comment: then try the @Paul suggestions ?

Comment: @Paul it seems like a good option but if I am not wrong, I will have to do it everytime there is an `imread`.

Comment: Just wrap the flip together with `imread`: `def imread(*arg, **kwargs): img = plt.imread(*args, **kwargs); img = np.flipud(img); return img`

Comment: @Paul tried it and the origin is still at top left.

Comment: @Paul tried it and the origin is still at top left. Tried drawing a circle at `(0,0)` on original and flipped one and the axes are flipped (and the image) but the origin remains at top left only. I just want that the origin to be at bottom left with no changes in image. I am not sure now whether this is possible. I am using blender to generate images and to be processed by opencv and blender has origin at bottom left. I have already come a bit too far to change origin in blender and start with image generation hence wanted to change it in openCV.

Comment: If you are still having problems, then post a minimal working example with code and images. Trying to debug by guessing what you might be doing wrong is a bit laborious.

Comment: Added some code and images. @Paul

Comment: I don't see a problem. The bottom image is flipped as requested in the original question?! Your circle is in the lower left hand corner with respect to original image. If you want to display the image in the original orientation, flip is back before calling `imshow`: `def imshow(name, array): return cv.imshow(name, np.flipud(array))`

Comment: @Paul it works, thank you so much! If you can post as an answer I can obviously accept it :)

Comment: just flip the image as you did and before displaying/imwrite, flip it back.

Comment: _" it would be a one time operation and would serve the purpose given that operation is not costly"_ - note that flip is `O(1)` - independent of the image size - as it does not perform a copy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverse the height (or column) pixels will get the result below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

img = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/flip_body.png') # read as color image
flip = img[::-1,:,:] # revise height in (height, width, channel)

plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1]), plt.title('original'), plt.show()
plt.imshow(flip[:,:,::-1]), plt.title('flip vertical'), plt.show()
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1]), plt.title('original with inverted y-axis'), plt.gca().invert_yaxis(), plt.show()
plt.imshow(flip[:,:,::-1]), plt.title('flip vertical with inverted y-axis'), plt.gca().invert_yaxis(), plt.show()
```

Output images:

[image]

Above included the one you intended to do?

Comment: I got the results from what @Paul suggested above in the comments. I just wanted that the origin be at the bottom left corner. But the image to look just like the original one.

Comment: Same as the "flip vertical with inverted y-axis" image in my reply? i.e. the last image.

Comment: Yes it is. Can you explain a bit what is happening here? You flipped the image and then inverted the y-axis? Am I right?  I am sorry if I sound a bit stupid but how does this make the origin to be at bottom left? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @lost_inthesis Sure. Firstly, `OpenCV` read the color image which consists of `(height(0:n), width(0:m), channel(B,G,R)`. If only flip it vertically by reversing the `height`, ie. `img[::-1,:,:]` , `0` of y-axis still starts from top-left. So, invert the y-axis `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` would flip the image once again and make the `0` of y-axis start from bottom-left.

Comment: That really helped thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @lost_inthesis Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @lost_inthesis voted up your question. Could you give me a vote up? Thanks.

Comment: @lost_inthesis btw, `img[:,:,::-1]` in `plt.imshow()` is for reversing the color channels as `OpenCV` read color image as `BGR` instead of `RGB`.